# JAXB generating JAXBElement<String> instead of String

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

I am using `Apache CXF` `cxf-codegen-plugin` `Maven` plugin to generate sources from `WSDL` file. Problem is that I get `JAXBElement<String>` generated instead of `String`. I have added the `jaxb-bindings.xml` file which looks like this:

```xml
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This should prevent `JAXB` to generate `JAXBElement<String>`. But it is not working I still have `JAXBElement<String>` generated instead of `String`.

My `Maven` plugin looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.runtime.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-jaxb</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <additionalJvmArgs>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</additionalJvmArgs>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/Cubiks.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>${basedir}/jaxb-bindings.xml</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>${basedir}/jaxws-bindings.xml</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                            <extraarg></extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/CubiksCallBackService.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>${basedir}/jaxws-bindings.xml</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>${basedir}/jaxb-bindings.xml</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>com.cubiks.ws.callback</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                            <extraarg></extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`CXF` version is `2.6.0`. Does someone know where might be the problem?

**EDIT**

The XSD is very huge. This is the element which generating `JAXBElement<String>`

```
  <xs:complexType name="ServiceResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RequestStatus" type="tns:RequestStatus"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RequestStatusDescription" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ServiceResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:ServiceResponse"/>
```

And the generated source is:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "RequestStatusDescription", namespace = "http://www.cubiksonline.com/2009/08/AssessmentProvider", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> requestStatusDescription;
```

Comment: Plz provide wsdl file and, if you have, xsd

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What I had to do is to wrap `jaxb:globalBindings` with another `jaxb:bindings`.

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Now everything is working, there is no `JAXBElement<String>` generated anymore.

Comment: Happy to report this solution works in JDeveloper as well. Just create an xml file then pass it in the wizard at the phase when you specify the URL/location of the WSDL.

Comment: This worked in NetBeans 8.2 as well. Right click on the service and "edit web service  attributes". Then go to "WSDL customization" tab and at the bottom under "External Binding Files" add this file and regenerate. All Strings resolved as String. Tanks!

Comment: Where do you add this snippet ? @PauliusMatulionis

Answer (score 12):

You can't have nillable and minoccurs together. Remove the minoccurs as it doesn't make sense for strings anyway.

Comment: And why is that I can't have them together? By the way the wsdl file is provided by the client, we didn't create it. I understand that they does not make sense, but it its not for me to decide to remove them or not.

Comment: If the schema has both then you need a JAXBElement to be able to distinguish between the cases where the XML element is missing (allowed by minOccurs) and where it is present but `xsi:nil`. If the schema only allowed one or the other then you wouldn't need the JAXBElement as a `null` property value would be enough.

Comment: [This post](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/JAXBElement-in-generated-java-classes-tp4933735p4934002.html) explains it nicely.

Comment: Well what does it mean for a string to be nillable and have minoccurs=0? What would the XML look like if those condition were met? Anyway have a look at [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) to make sure you are using the binding correctly there is an example Showing how to configure the maven plugin. Your binding file is correct though I suspect if you configure your maven plugin correctly it will work. Since you can't change the wsdl this is your only option.

Comment: That's odd, I wrapped my globalBindings with jaxb:bindings and it worked. 

<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

I still can't understand why.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to add in your jaxb-binding.xml:

```xml
<jaxb:bindings ... xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
        <xjc:simple />
        <!-- ... -->
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: I am trying to add it but I am getting: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: The "xjc:simple" customization is not associated with any schema element.

Comment: I have managed to <xjc:simple /> correctly but still the same. JAXBElement<String> is generated.

Comment: Right, I've now checked out a WS to test, it's the `generateElementProperty="false"` attribute which avoids the `JAXBElement` wrapper in my case. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

I created a file named `bindings.xml` in my recourses folder, and added the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:simple /><!-- it did only work after adding this -->
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:schema>
```

Then I mentioned this file in my cxf plugin definition in the pom.xml as in :

in `<wsdlOptions>` tag , in `<wsdlOption>` where it has  the path for the wsdl file, I added a  tag which has:

```
<bindingFiles> 
 <bindingFile> ${basedir}/src/min/resources/bindings.xml </bindingFile>  
</bindingFiles>
```

My stubs got generated so prettily with actual types.

Answer (score 0):

When we have both `minouucrs=0` and `nillable=true` in XSD it will generate JAXBElement. To avoid this we need to remove either of the one.

If you use `generateElementProperty="false"` property when generating POJO objects from XSD scheme then it will be working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I have had duplicated elements in my wsdl schema, that is why CXF generated JAXBElement instead of string. Be careful.