# How can I set generateElementProperty as a local property in the bindings file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, wsdl

I'm having an issue with jaxb. One of my elements is requiring me to set a `JAXBElement<String>`, instead of just a `String`. I know that a solution to this is to change the xsd, as discussed here [JAXB generating JAXBElement<String> instead of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508741/jaxb-generating-jaxbelementstring-instead-of-string), but the xsd was provided by the vendor, and we can't convince them to change it.

Apparently another solution is to specify a property `<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">`, which would turn off the `JAXBElements` globally, which is also not what we want.

According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-1072/ahiid/index.html), it should be possible to set `generateElementProperty="false"` locally in a `<jaxb:property>` customization. How can I do that in a bindings file? The only examples I can find (like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148590%29)) seem to be setting it directly in the xsd -- and if I could change that, I'd just remove the minOccurs.

My current bindings file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XXXPrivateService.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:noValidator />
      <xjc:serializable />
    </jxb:globalBindings>
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="com.XXX.YYYY.xsd.XXXprivateservice">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>TODO</body>]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XXXPrivateService_1_2.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="com.XXX.YYYY.xsd.XXXprivateservice.two">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>TODO</body>]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XXXPrivateService_1_2_3.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="com.XXX.YYYY.xsd.XXXprivateservice.three">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>TODO</body>]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XXXPrivateService_1_2_3_4.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="com.XXX.YYYY.xsd.XXXprivateservice.four">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>TODO</body>]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>


  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XXXPrivateService_1_2_3_4_5.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="com.XXX.YYYY.xsd.XXXprivateservice.five">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>TODO</body>]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XXXPrivateService_1_2_3_4_5_6.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="com.XXX.YYYY.xsd.XXXprivateservice.six">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>TODO</body>]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XXXPrivateService_1_2_3_4_5_6_7.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="com.XXX.YYYY.xsd.XXXprivateservice.seven">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>TODO</body>]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

The offending portion of the XSD looks like this:

```
  <xs:element name="PayWithPointsRedemption">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="requestSourceId" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="rewardsAccountId" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="XXXReferenceId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="externalChannelCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="payWithPointsRedemptionDetails" nillable="true" type="q4:ArrayOfPayWithPointsRedemptionDetail" xmlns:q4="http://ZZZZZ.YYYY.com/XXXRewards"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to set it locally in your external binding like this

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xyz.xsd"
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <!-- ... -->
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:bindings
        node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='PayWithPointsRedemption']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence">
        <jxb:property generateElementProperty="false" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Make sure the XPath expression in `jxb:bindings` matches!