# Extracting values frm XML file using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to manipulate data from an XML file and inserting these values in to a database. I have a problem extracting a data from a particular XML tag. 
This XML tag contains alphanumeric values but about 95% (if not 99%) of the time, the values it contains are integers. Therefore I treat these values as a `String`.

```
<reference>12345</reference>
```

Moreover, the corresponding column in the database is a `varchar`. 
I created an `XSD` file making sure that the the element `reference` is of type `xsd:string`

```
<xs:element name="reference" type="xs:string" />
```

The problem is that I can have an XML file where some references are of this format:

```
<reference>012345</reference>
<reference>0012345</reference>
```

Extracting the value of these references removes the leading zeros giving me `12345` as the resulting value. I don't understand why. I feel like JAXB is treating the values as integers.

How can I go about getting the right values?

**Edit**:

Here's the corresponding POJO
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"referenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes"
})
public static class Programme {

```
@XmlElementRefs({

    @XmlElementRef(name = "reference", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    /** other @XmlElementRef  */
})
protected List<JAXBElement<?>> referenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes;
```

The funny thing is that in the get method of the above variable, the JAXB specifies the objects that are allowed to the list. Only `String` and other POJO objects created by JAXB using the XSD files are allowed. There is no mention of `Integers` allowed.

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the referenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the referenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getReferenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list 
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 *  ...
 *  ...
 *  ...
 */

public List<JAXBElement<?>> getReferenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes() {
    if (referenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes == null) {
        referenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<?>>();
    }
    return this.referenceOrDescriptionOrEnseignes;
}
```

Bizarrely, when I print the class type of the reference element, it prints `Integer`.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the corresponding POJO containing the `reference` element look?

Comment: I don't understand why you get `JAXBElement`s instead of plain `String`s. Were the classes generated using the XSD? Is the `reference` element in the XSD  part of a `choice` element or something similar?

Comment: Yes I don't get that either. Yes the classes were generated using the XSD. The `reference` element isn't part of a choice. It's part of another larger object. Oh I just noticed that required attribute is `false` which isn't right. But that's another matter.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help (at least with getting plain Strings): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508741/jaxb-generating-jaxbelementstring-instead-of-string

Comment: @Petter: Ok I'll check it out.

Comment: @Petter: I can't believe my mistake. After changing the `reference` element from `xs:unSignedShort` (its former value) to `xs:string`, I overwrote the previous JAXB classes with the generated ones. But I didn't overwrite the `ObjectFactory` class. I thought the `ObjectFactory` class is useful only if you want to create an XML file from the POJOs. It seems that JAXB uses the ObjectFactory internally though I'm not sure how. I checked the classes generated by JAXB and none of them contained an instance of this factory. I suspect it's during (un) marshalling. Well, I just lost a day debugging :(

Comment: @Petter: Do you have any idea how JAXB uses the `ObjectFactory` class?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to print this value before inserting into database.

Cross check your POJO.

Comment: Yes I printed the values out and they were without the leading zeros. I edited my question to add the POJO.